# Visual Studio licensing per user or per machine

Tags: visual-studio, licensing

I have been using VS2010 Pro from DreamSpark. I will shortly be joining a commercial organisation who will not be providing me with a VS license and as such I will need to purchase my own.

Is Visual Studio licensed per user, per machine, or per-user per-machine? I.e. if I buy one license am I able to exclusively use it on both my laptop and desktop?

Thanks

Comment: Can you legally use a DreamSpark version for commercial use?

Comment: Also seems weird you're being hired by a company to do VS work but they won't provide it for you.

Comment: @Ben - I agree on both counts (yeah, I realize the first one is a question). I don't think the DreamSpark version is good for commercial use, although I didn't specifically see it prohibited.

Comment: It's more of a contracting than employee-based role. I like to be legit which is why I'm purchasing as opposed to using DreamSpark. I could probably use BizSpark (or whatever the business-based one is) but I'd rather buy/own outright. Cheers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Comment: NO, you're absolutely not allowed to use DreamSpark VS licence for commercial use!

Comment: I proposed re-opening this question because it's a perfectly valid question dealing with programming tools.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Visual Studio is licensed per user. You can have one installation on your laptop and another on your desktop as long as they are both used by you only (or any other user has a license). Here's [Microsoft's whitepaper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13350) on licensing.

Comment: I may have spoke too soon. DreamSpark licenses appear to be single install.

Comment: I believe you'll find both BizSpark and DreamSpark have specific licensing conditions that depend on circumstances, but if you buy stock license, it shouldn't be an issue. FWIW our BizSpark licenses a few years ago were valid for 10 activations (and you could request multiple keys per registered account) so no technical enforcement of limitations (but also no reason to breach license since it was free and largely unlimited)

Comment: Here is an excerpt from the mentioned Whitepaper:  "The licensed user can install and use the software on any number of devices. The software can be installed and used on
your devices at work, at home, at school, and even on devices at a customer’s office or on dedicated hardware hosted by a
3 rd party. Most subscriber software can also be run in Microsoft Azure VMs. However, the software is otherwise not
licensed for use in production environments. "